# Exchange 2010 HUB Transport Rule not working

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, rules

We have an Exchange Server 2010 running on Windows Server 2010 Standard SP2.
I'm having problems with configuring a hub transport rule.
The purpose of the rule is to block all emails that are coming from outside the organization to the recipients of a security group.
It goes as follows:

> Apply rule to messages
>
> from users that are 'Outside the organization'
>
> and sent to a member of 'Security-group@domain.tld'
>
> send 'Email to the recipient is restricted by system administrator' to sender with '5.7.1'
>
> except when message is from 'something@something.smth(2 such exceptions exist)
>
> or except when the From address contains 'something.smth'(8 such exceptions exists)

The problem is that the rule does not apply.

I've included some user accounts in the security group in Active Directory and made a test by sending them e-mail from a @gmail account - gmail not being in the exceptions list ofc and the user receives the email.

I've tried restarting the MS Exchange Transport Service - to no success & Restarting the whole server - to no success.

Same identical story with a rule denying the same security group the ability to send e-mails outside the organization.

I do want to mention that the rule applying a disclaimer to e-mails sent outside the organization applies though.

Comment: Only a clue, but in exchanhe 2010+ the incoming rule you can do is limited, ms force more the edge role

Comment: What versions do you have? There is no Server 2010 Standard SP2. 
If you remove the exceptions, does the rule fire?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

When I checked the properties of the security group in AD I saw that it no longer had an e-mail address in the e-mail address field.

I then tried to make a new rule, and in the rule creation wizard when I was supposed to select the group to which the rule would apply, I could no longer see the security group.

I created a new distribution group linked to the security one and it started to work again.

Comment: How exactly the security group "lost" it's e-mail address is another, longer story. Anyhow, I'm glad it's over.